# ¿Podria alguien ayudarme con este programa en nasm?

Tags: ensamblador, stdin, x86, nasm

Cuando intento leer desde el teclado un numero de 2 digitos y luego intento imprimir ese numero de nuevo en pantalla no me regresa el mismo valor, en cambio si defino el numero yo mismo si funciona, ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
segment .data
segment .bss
  datos resb 2
  aux resb 2
segment .text
global _start
_start:
  ;SYSCALL
  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, aux
  mov edx, 2
  int 0x80

  mov edx, 0  
  ;mov eax, 55 ; DEFINIENDO EL VALOR SI SE MUESTRA CORRECTAMENTE
  mov eax, [aux]; USANDO EL VALOR ALMACENADO EN AUX NO SE MUESTRA CORRECTAMENTE
  mov ecx, 10
  ; SE REALIZA UNA DIVISION ENTRE 10 PARA TRABAJAR CON NUMEROS DE 2 DIGITOS
  div ecx
  ; SE LE SUMA AL RESIDUO Y AL COCIENTE '0' PARA PODER IMPRIMIR EN PANTALLA CADA UNO DE LOS DIGITOS
  add eax, '0'
  mov [datos+0], eax
  add edx, '0'
  mov [datos+1], edx
  ;SYSCALL
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, datos
  mov edx, 2
  int 80h
_salir:
   mov eax, 1
   xor ebx, ebx
   int 0x80
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradeceria

Comment: ¿Qué números tecleas y qué se muestra? ¿Eres consciente que si pulsas la tecla 1 obtendrás el número correspondiente al carácter `'1'` (seguramente 49)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que lo que tienes en `aux` no es el número tecleado en binario, sino la secuencia de caracteres ascii que el usuario tecleó.

Suponiendo que son sólo dos caracteres y ambos son dígitos, el siguiente fragmento te serviría para leerlos y dejar en EAX (en `AL` en realidad) el número que representan:

```
  mov eax, 0      ; Borrar parte alta del registro por si acaso
  mov al, [aux]   ; Leemos el primer dígito (ascii)
  sub al, '0'     ; sustraemos el ascii del cero
  mov ecx, 10
  mul cl          ; y multiplicamos por 10
  mov bl, [aux+1] ; Leemos el segundo dígito (ascii)
  sub bl, '0'     ; restarle el ascii del 0
  add al, bl      ; y añadirlo a lo que teníamos en al
```